# CMDbuild e-mail

Tags: email, cmd

I know that there is a option in cmdbuild that permits you yo setup incoming and outgoing mail servers.
I was wondering if there is a way in cmdbuild to send e-mails with certain triggers.

Can i get CMDB to issue automaticaclly an e-mail to an e-mail adress for example that i have two weeks before x license expire?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the Microsoft Windows `cmd.exe` shell? If not, then the `cmd` tag should probably be replaced by `shell`.

Comment: Have you looked through the [cmdbuild](http://www.cmdbuild.org/en/documentazione/manuali) documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to know that CMDBuild can send an email only during a process.If you want for example to recive an email for all the sofware whose license expires in x days from now, you can set up a process that can check which are the licenses, after that send an email containing the information that you wanted.
After that you can schedule this process to be executed every day or whenever you want